# How to convert string result of enum with overridden toString() back to enum?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration, converters

Given the following java enum:

```
public enum AgeRange {

   A18TO23 {
        public String toString() {        
            return "18 - 23";
        }
    },
   A24TO29 {
        public String toString() {        
            return "24 - 29";
        }
    },
   A30TO35 {
        public String toString() {        
            return "30 - 35";
        }
    },

}
```

Is there any way to convert a string value of "18 - 23"  to the corresponding enum value i.e. AgeRange.A18TO23  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best and simplest way to do it is like this:

```
public enum AgeRange {
    A18TO23 ("18-23"),
    A24TO29 ("24-29"),
    A30TO35("30-35");

    private String value;

    AgeRange(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }

    public static AgeRange getByValue(String value){
        for (final AgeRange element : EnumSet.allOf(AgeRange.class)) {
            if (element.toString().equals(value)) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to invoke the `getByValue()` method with the `String` input in it.

Comment: I agree that it's nice to put the value in the constructor. For very large enums (and they would really have to be pretty big) it would make sense to use a map.

I'd personally return from inside the loop as well, but then I've never been a fan of "return from one place regardless of readability" :)

Comment: One other point - it would be better to use EnumSet.allOf instead of AgeRange.values() as otherwise you create a new array for every call.

Comment: Very interesting.  A lot of what's happening in the code is new to me.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: instead of your method, `getByValue(String)`, shouldn't you just delegate to the enum's inherent `valueOf(String)`?  reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914792/where-does-the-enum-valueofstring-method-come-from

Answer (score 7):

You could always create a map from string to value - do so statically so you only need to map it once, assuming that the returned string remains the same over time. There's nothing built-in as far as I'm aware.

Comment: This is a much better way to handle this.  The map is then created when the enum is, and operates much faster than iterating an array.

Comment: I am considering this method as well, but I have only around 15 values in this enum.  Is it still more efficient to create a map?

Comment: Probably not, to be honest. Hash tables are great for large amounts of data, but I suspect comparing 15 values (at worst) will be about as fast as getting the hashcode, finding the right bucket etc.

Answer (score 4):

According to effective java (2nd ed) item 30, it can be (it is much faster than the loop)

```
public enum AgeRange {
       A18TO23("18-23"),
       A24TO29("24-29"),
       A30TO35("30-35");

       private final String value;

       AgeRange(String value){
          this.value = value;
       }

       @Override public String toString(){
           return value;
       }

       private static final Map<String, AgeRange> stringToEnum =
           new HashMap<String, AgeRange>();

       static {
           for (AgeRange r : values()) {
               stringToEnum.put(r.toString(), r);
           }
       }

       public static AgeRange getByValue(String value){
           return stringToEnum.get(value);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (AgeRange ar: EnumSet.allOf(AgeRange)) {
    if (ar.toString().equals(inString)) {
         myAnswer = ar;
         break;
    }
}
```

Or something like that?  Just typed in, haven't run through a compiler.  Forgive (comment on) typos...

Or use logic like this to build a map once.  Avoid iteration at runtime.  Good idea, Jon.

Answer (score 2):

The class overrides "toString()" - so, to get the reverse operation, you need to override `valueOf()` to translate the output of `toString()` back to the Enum values.

```
public enum AgeRange {

   A18TO23 {
        public String toString() {        
                return "18 - 23";
        }
        public AgeRange valueOf (Class enumClass, String name) {
                return A18T023
        }
    },

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Buyer beware - uncompiled and untested...

The mechanism for `toString()` and `valueOf()` is a documented part of the [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

Comment: Should that second be valueOf method?

Comment: -1 If I'm not mistaken, the advice on valueOf here is ... wrong, to be gentle ;-).  `valueOf()` is static, and of no use in the body of a particular enum value.  And even once all this is fixed, the "correct" implementation would be wrong, in that the compiler doesn't allow a static override on `static public valueOf(String)`.  The common fix is to simply not use `valueOf` - use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following?

```
static AgeRange fromString(String range) {
    for (AgeRange ageRange : values()) {
        if (range.equals(ageRange.toString())) {
            return ageRange;
        }
    }
    return null;   
}
```

Or, as others suggested, using a caching approach:

```
private static Map<String, AgeRange> map;

private static synchronized void registerAgeRange(AgeRange ageRange) {
    if (map == null) {
        map = new HashMap<String, AgeRange>();
    }
    map.put(ageRange.toString(), ageRange);
}

AgeRange() {
    registerAgeRange(this);
}

static AgeRange fromString(String range) {
    return map.get(range);
}
```