# "-" separated strings in enum java

Tags: java, enums, compilation

I have a problem in creating an enumeration in Java using "-"-separated strings:

```
public enum CipherList{

   RSA-MD5,AES128-SHA,AES256-SHA;
}
```

I am getting compilation errors.

Comment: Why do you need the dashes in the identifiers? Because I think you'd need something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9781903/737620)

Comment: `-` is not valid inside an identifier (as it would be confused by the minus sign / substraction operation. Anyway next time provide more information about the error if you expect some reply

Answer (score 9):

The `-` symbol may not be used in an identifier in Java. (How would `RSA-MD5` be parsed if `RSA` and `MD5` happened to be integers?)

I suggest you use

```
RSA_MD5, AES128_SHA, AES256_SHA;
```

according to the Java coding conventions for constants <sup>[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums)</sup>.

Comment: Cant i have it as a string, coz I am going to use the same values for processing ..

Comment: You mean that you will use values returned by name() during processing?

Answer (score 3):

Enum constants have to use valid Java identifiers, and identifiers are not allowed to contain dashes.

You could, for example, replace dashes with underscores:

```
public enum CipherList{
   RSA_MD5, AES128_SHA, AES256_SHA;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use exact strings using enums you can use following approach.

```
enum CipherList{
   CHIP_ONE("RSA-MD5"),CHIP_TWO("AES128-SHA"),CHIP_THREE("AES256-SHA");
   private String code;
   CipherList(String code) {
      code= code;
   }
   String getcode() {
      return code;
   } 
}
```